# What are the differences between these web units?

Tags: html, css

What are the differences between these web units? What are the pros and cons, and the appropriate time to use each of them?

px, ex, em, pt, %

Comment: Several more good ones: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=em+px+pt

Comment: I'm beginning to get the feeling we're here to do custom web searches, not answer questions...

Comment: @mellamokb: I got really lazy, so I wrote an answer instead. Wait a minute...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`px` stands for pixels. Exactly what it says on the tin: each dot on your screen is a pixel.

`ex` refers to the x-height of the given font, i.e. the height of the lowercase letter x for that font.

`em` refers to the maximum height required by a font. It is a commonly-used relative font size because it is calculated based on the computed font size of an element (or its parent if inherited).

`pt` stands for typographic point, which is 1/72 of an inch.

`%` is the percentage relative to a given property otherwise inherited from an element's parent.

Note that `em` and `%` work the same way. Ems are something like the decimal representation of percentages, i.e. 1 = 100%, 0.01 = 1%.

You can find more units at the [CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values).